# C Convert comma separated string to array

Tags: c, arrays, string, csv, split

I have an archive with comma separated string I want to slip every line into 2 arrays: v[i].date and v[i].value.
However, when I run the code it shows random values for the arrays.
Is there anything I should change?

> Input
>   1761
>   02/20/18,11403.7
>   02/19/18,11225.3
>   02/18/18,10551.8
>   02/17/18,11112.7
>   02/16/18,10233.9

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct{
    char data[10];
    double valor;

}vetor;

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    FILE *csv;



        if((csv=fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL  )
        {
            printf("not found csv\n");
            exit(1);
        }


        long int a=0;

        char linha[256];

        char *token = NULL;

        if(fgets(linha, sizeof(linha), csv))
        {
            token = strtok(linha, "\n");
            a =(atoi(token));
        }


        printf("%d\n", a);

        rewind(csv);

        vetor *v;

        v=(vetor*)malloc(a*sizeof(vetor));

        char linha2[256];

        while (fgets(linha2, sizeof(linha2), csv) != 0)
        {
            fseek(csv, +1, SEEK_CUR);

            for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
            {   
                fscanf(csv, "%s[^,]", v[i].data);
                fscanf(csv, "%lf[^\n]", &v[i].valor);

            }
        }

        printf("%d\n", v[0].valor);


    fclose(csv);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Putting `fopen()` on a separate line, like `FILE *csv = fopen(...);` and then `if ( csv == NULL )...` makes for much more understandable and  maintainable code.  There's no reason to stuff all that into the `if` statement.  That style becomes incomprehensible and bug-prone as code gets more complex.  Look at how many pairs of parenthesis you had to put in for just one call to `fopen()`.

Comment: What is the `rewind` and `fseek` good for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `fscanf()` calls are off: When you make this call

```
fscanf(csv, "%s[^,]", v[i].data);
```

`fscanf()` will first parse a string of non-whitespace characters until it finds a whitespace character (the `%s` conversion), so `"02/20/18,11403.7"` gets written to your array, and your buffer will overflow. After that, you are in undefined behavior territory, and anything could happen. **The `[^,]` conversion won't even be reached before you get UB.**

Of course, you can simply fix this by dropping the `%s` from your format string, but I think, what you really want to do, is to just parse all the numbers as numbers:

```
int month, day, year;
double value;
int conversionCount = fscanf(csv, "%d/%d/%d,%lf\n", &month, &day, &year, &value);
if(conversionCount != 4) {
    handleError();
}
```

Do not forget to check the result of `fscanf()` as it's the only way to know whether parsing completed successfully. I have added `\n` at the end of the format string, which will gobble up any whitespace following the float value, including the newline character. This allows you to perform your conversions one line at a time with a single `fscanf()` in a simple loop, without any need to call `fseek()`. Just keep parsing lines until an `fscanf()` call returns something other than the number of conversions you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` field only holds one `char` now. It needs to have room for at least the typical value, like 02/19/18.

Use `char[10]` for example (if you know for sure that it can never be longer than 9 characters).

I think the compiler ought to have warned against your `fscanf` call.

Comment: OK, I changed it, but now the output for v[i].data and v[i].valor are all zeros.